# MacBook swiping between workstations not working

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, trackpad, multi-touch

I have seen people using two, three, or four fingers swipe left and right across to move to different workspaces and apps (i.e. Google, Spotify, or Discord) I can swipe up and down with three fingers to show all my workspaces, but swiping left and right does not work. These are my current settings. I have tried restarting, no fix.

[image: Screenshot of the 'More Gestures' tab in Trackpad settings]